# Accept Cookies inside Java code?

Tags: java, sockets, cookies

I'm dealing with a HTTP sockets project, I have to send 2 HTTP GET requests from my java code like this :

- Request 1 : call page X
- Page X is setting a cookie.
- Request 2 : call to page Y

as you see to access the content of page Y i cookie must be present...

how to accept a cookie from java code please ?

Here's a sample sent request :

```
      String sServer = "example.com";
          InetAddress inaddr = null;

          try {
              inaddr = InetAddress.getByName(sServer);
      }
      catch (UnknownHostException ex) { //The host could not be resolved.
              System.out.println(ex);
              System.out.println("Error resolving hostname for '" + sServer + "'.\n");

      }
      Socket sock = null;
      try {
              sock = new Socket(inaddr, 80);
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);
          System.out.println("Could not create the socket.\n");

      }

try {
java.io.OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
 String sPacket = "GET /xxx/xxx/xxx.do HTTP/1.1\n"                                                              + "Host: example.com\n"
+ "Connection: keep-alive\n"                                                    + "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.1.249.1064 Safari/532.5\n"
+ "Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8\n\n";

              os.write(sPacket.getBytes(), 0, sPacket.length());

              //Let's get the answer.
              System.out.print("The server (" + sServer + ") answered: '");
              java.io.InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
              for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                      if (buf[i] == 0) break;
                      else
                          System.out.print(new Character((char)buf[i]));
              }
              System. out.print("'\n");

      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);

      }
```

Comment: at least post the code you've written so far, rather than asking us to do it all for you

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying, i'm not asking you to do it all no, i just need the name of the class/method responsible for this :)
i updated my post sorry.

Comment: Why are you re-implementing HTTP, when Java has a perfectly good HTTP API?

Comment: AAGHH! My eyes! If you use an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans, please use code formatting. In eclipse it is: Ctrl - Shift - F.

Comment: Sorry guys for the ugly code :) I'll try to rewrite this using java's httpclient. thanks..

Comment: Although HttpClient is excellent, it's good to know that Java provides a standard API for connecting an URL: `java.net.URLConnection`. Also see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or another library dedicated to HTTP processing, rather than trying to implement/interpret the protocol yourself. See [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html) for how to handle cookies using HttpClient.